# Weird error when invoking soap - llegalAccessError: tried to access field org.apache.cxf.staxutils.OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter.isOverlaid

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

Ive been working on a soap client since a time and I still cannot figure it out.

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.apache.cxf.staxutils.OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter.isOverlaid from class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJStreamWriter
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJStreamWriter.getPrefix(SAAJStreamWriter.java:79)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.writeSoapEnvelopeStart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:87)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invokeWrapped(ClientImpl.java:312)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:321)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:240)
        at com.sigetel.web.web.rest.consumer.SoapClient.invoke(SoapClient.java:63)
        at com.sigetel.web.web.rest.consumer.SoapClient.main(SoapClient.java:37)
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60128', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I saw its kinda common but still cannot make it work.

Here is my code:

```
 Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
        SOAPMessage response;
        SOAPBody responseBody;
        dispatch.getRequestContext().put(Dispatch.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, true);
        dispatch.getRequestContext().put(Dispatch.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, soapActionUri);
        try {
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
            StreamSource msgSrc = new StreamSource(new StringReader(request));
            soapPart.setContent(msgSrc);
            message.saveChanges();


            response = dispatch.invoke(message);
            responseBody = response.getSOAPBody();
....
```

Reelevant dependencies that might be related:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

### EDITED:

and these ones:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea about this error?

Comment: Do you know versions of other cxf packages, namely cxf-rt-bindings-soap and cxf-core/cxf-api, that are used by your runtime?

Comment: not really, Ive updated my dependencies, maybe you can take a look

Comment: But still it's impossible to get which package loaded SAAJStreamWriter and OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter. I think you can simply search for them in your runtime libraries.

Answer (score 5):

As you may have already noticed, you have incompatible versions of [SAAJStreamWriter](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/binding/soap/saaj/SAAJStreamWriter.html) and [OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/staxutils/OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter.html).

`SAAJStreamWriter` is located in package `cxf-rt-bindings-soap`, which is provided by:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

`OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter` is located in pachage `cxf-core`, which is provided by:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Try one of the latest versions of [org.apache.cxf](http://cxf.apache.org/) - 3.1.13 or 3.2.0 - the same version for both dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

You are pulling incorrect version of `OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter`.

`SAAJStreamWriter` extends `OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter` which has `isOverlaid` field.

The `isOverlaid` was changed from package private to protected in 3.2 version and was backported to 3.1.7 version so it can accessed in sub class `SAAJStreamWriter`

Both the below dependencies is pulling cxf core which has `OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter`

1.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

**cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws - cxf-rt-bindings-soap - 3.1.11 for SAAJStreamWriter**

cxf-rt-transports-http - cxf-core - 3.1.11 for OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter

2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**cxf-rt-transports-http - cxf-core - 3.1.6 for OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter**

cxf core 3.1.6 was chosen over 3.1.11 since it is nearer as by default maven resolves version conflicts with a nearest-wins strategy.

So in essence 3.1.11 `SAAJStreamWriter` class was expecting 3.1.11 `OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter` but found 3.1.6 `OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter` where the `isOverlaid` was package private and is the reason for your error.

**Fix** change to use 3.1.11 for jetty dependency or atleast use version 3.1.7 for both above dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

This will pull the `3.1.11` for both cxf core and cxf bindings and should resolve the error.